# How to change position of buttons to required location inside window?

Tags: html, css, jqxwidgets

I have a small doubt regarding styling of my window, I want these two buttons that are on the screen to appear on the bottom right corner of my window. What are the required stylings that i need to give this tag to make the buttons appear at the bottom.
I have attached an image of how the position is needed to be altered:css styling doubt

[image]

help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Share working code that  you have tried.. and also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share what have you tried. Kindly read the [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right: -290px;">submit</button>

<button style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right: -215px;">cancel</button>
```

this seemed to sort the probelm i was having about positioning the buttons. thanks for your inputs everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try like this you can achieve what you want.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="buttons">
   <button>submit</button>
    <button>reset</button>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the two buttons inside a div and set the div **id="something"**. Then define the css of the #something.

```
#something{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
}
```